# Why Resources.Load does not work without systemTypeInstance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Unity `Resource.Load` [function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) has two overloaded methods - one just with path to asset and another asks for Type systemTypeInstance. There is no info why I should use one method or another. But when I tried Resources.Load with only one param it returned null, and with adding second param everything was ok. For example
`Sprite asd = Resources.Load("test") as Sprite;` returns null, but
`Sprite asd = Resources.Load("test", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;` returns sprite at `"Assets/Resources/test"`. What for I have to add second param? Why is it neccessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What for I have to add second param? Why is it necessary?

**1**.`Sprite asd = Resources.Load("test") as Sprite;` which do **not** work and returns null uses the overload below:

```
public static Object Load(string path);
```

---

**2**.`Sprite asd = Resources.Load("test", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;` which works as expected is using the overload below:

```
public static Object Load(string path, Type systemTypeInstance);
```

There are other overloads which uses generics.

---

There are other overloads which uses *generics* but these two matter in this question.

When you import your image and set the *Texture Type* to *Sprite(2D and UI)*, it becomes a type of [`Sprite`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html). The problem is that the first overload in **#1** is using Unity's [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) as the default Type not `Sprite`. It also returns Unity `Object`. It looks like this:

```
public static Object Load(string path)
{
    return Load(path, typeof(Object));
}
```

The issue with the first code is when you performed the casting from Unity `Object` to `Sprite` with `as Sprite`. If you do the casting as Unity's `Object`, it should work.

Example:

The following which uses the `Resources.Load` function without the second parameter **works**:

```
//OK
UnityEngine.Object asd = Resources.Load("test") as UnityEngine.Object;
```

The *asd* variable **should not** be `null`. It should load the object but you **can't** cast it to `Sprite`.

Now, when you cast it to `Sprite`, it will be `null` because you **can't** convert Unity's `Object` to `Sprite`. Read the comments from the code below:

```
//OK
UnityEngine.Object asd = Resources.Load("test") as UnityEngine.Object;
//NOT OK(NULL)
Sprite obj1 = asd as Sprite; 
//NOT OK(NULL) + InvalidCastException
Sprite obj2 = (Sprite)asd;
```

Again, it returns `null` due to the cast to `Sprite`.

---

This is why the second load function is added:

```
public static Object Load(string path, Type systemTypeInstance);
```

> **There is no info why I should use one method or another.**

**1**.*The first one is used to load a prefab*. When you create a GameObject, you can make it a prefab and put it in the Resources folder.

```
//OK
UnityEngine.Object asd = Resources.Load("test") as UnityEngine.Object;
//OK
GameObject obj2 = asd as GameObject;
```

OR

```
//OK
UnityEngine.Object asd = (GameObject)Resources.Load("test");
```

**2**.The second one is used to load files such as images(.png, jpeg) and audio, video, fbx. files.

For example, loading fbx file in the Resources folder:

```
//OK
Mesh model = Resources.Load("test", typeof(Mesh)) as Mesh;
//Not Ok
Mesh model2 = Resources.Load("test") as Mesh;
```

*Finally, you can't convert `UnityEngine.Object` to any other type if the `Object` to load is **not** a prefab. You can if it is a prefab. If it is a file like image, audio, video, it would be impossible to covert the `Object` to that type of file. It will even be impossible to convert it to `GameObject`.*

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, a `Sprite` is a type of texture so it's likely the call without the type argument is returning a `Texture2D` and then failing to cast (a sprite is essentially a sub-asset of a texture if you look at it in Unity's *Project* window.

This should be easy to determine with some debugging. Try saving it first as an `Object`, attach your debugger, and see what that call is actually returning before the cast:

```
Object testObj = Resources.Load("test");
Texture text = testObj as Texture2D; // Probably a valid Texture2D
Sprite spr = testObj as Sprite; // Probably null
```